# AJAX uniqueness verification not working on rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, validation

I am trying to validate the front end of my application. I am having issues with the ajax call I am using to figure out if the user is passing a unique email.

My JS:

```
    function appendResults(data) { 
  console.log(data);  
  if(data.message=='ERROR') {
    $("#confirmation").html("");
      var content = '<div class= "alert alert-danger">Este email ya se ha usado.</div>';
      $("#confirmation").append(content);
  }
  else if ($('#name').val() == '' || $('#surname').val() == '' || $('#email').val() == ''|| $('#estanco').val() == '' || $('#picture').val() == '')  {
      $("#confirmation").html("");
      var content = '<div class= "alert alert-danger">Debes rellenar todo el formulario.</div>';
      $("#confirmation").append(content);
    }
  else {
      $("#confirmation").html("");
      var content = '<div class= "alert alert-success"><strong>Genial!</strong> Ya participas en el concurso.</div>';
      $("#confirmation").append(content);
      co
}
}

function handleSubmitEvent(e) { 
    var formURL = '/contestants/new';
    var formData = $("#email").val();

    $.ajax({
        url: formURL,
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: appendResults,
        error: function() {console.log('There was an error')}
    });
    console.log(formData);
}

function attachFormListeners(e) {   
    $('#listed').click(handleSubmitEvent);
}

$(document).ready(attachFormListeners);
```

My controller:

```
def email_uniqueness
        if Contestant.where(params[:email]).exists?
            render json: {message: "SUCCESS"}
        else
            render json: {message: "ERROR"}
        end
    end
```

The 'ERROR' message keeps passing through even when a new email is set. Not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```
if Contestant.where(params[:email]).exists?
  render json: {message: "SUCCESS"}
else
  render json: {message: "ERROR"}
end
```

Looks like if the email exists, then you get a `'SUCCESS'`.

Else you would get the `'ERROR'`.

> The 'ERROR' message keeps passing through even when a new email is set. Not sure how to fix it.

Well yeah... if an email is not found then you've reach `'ERROR'`.

Comment: The only thing that could be potentially moved into the model is a scope that returns users with a given email, but given that it's easy enough like this or via a finder, doesn't seem worth it at this point. You still need to check for a dupe email in validation anyway, but doing a sanity check via Ajax seems perfectly reasonable, and you need a controller action to do that. Nothing tricky about Ajax via REST, not sure what you're trying to communicate there.

Comment: (Actually, re-reading the code, it's not immediately obvious what's happening: I had assumed this was a pre-submit check, but if it is, it's not shown here, so never mind that part of my comment.)

Comment: Hahaha! Using a `email_uniqueness` action is not very RESTful in my opinion. Single field validation can be achieved using only `create` and `update` and while using model validation.

Comment: It may be an ugly URL, but that doesn't make it non-RESTful. The OP has a mish-mash of techniques here; it's not using standard Rails validations, but is posting to `new`, so it's all messed up. If it is supposed to check email only, then creating a new route is perfectly reasonable and RESTful.